# CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class for bean with name defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/sping-servlet.xml]

Tags: spring, maven, jdbc

In spring-servlet.xml configration file of my maven spring project, It occurs an exception when I run project after build by maven.

```
INFO: Initializing Servlet 'spring'
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
Jun 19, 2019 4:05:10 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [daoImp.EmployeeCruzDaoImp] for bean with name 'dao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: daoImp.EmployeeCruzDaoImp
Jun 19, 2019 4:05:10 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [daoImp.EmployeeCruzDaoImp] for bean with name 'dao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: daoImp.EmployeeCruzDaoImp
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:663)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:630)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1491)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:826)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:696)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:662)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:710)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:587)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:526)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1089)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5270)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3828)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5608)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: daoImp.EmployeeCruzDaoImp
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1364)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1185)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:437)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1430)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1374)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: Please post code as text

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't add code/xml/stacktraces as images as those are unreadable. Please add the XML and actual class (including package!) as text with proper code tags. And please add the full stacktrace instead of a snippet.

Comment: Show your Spring configuration.

Comment: <bean id="ds"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName"
   value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url"
   value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_employee" />
  <property name="username" value="root"/>
  <property name="password" value="root"/>
 </bean>
 <bean id="jdbcTemplate"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>
 </bean>
 <bean class="daoImp.EmployeeCruzDaoImp">
  <property name="template" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>
 </bean>

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre].